# multi language feature support windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I just wonder if we could take advantage of multiple language support in windows phone 7, 7.5 in any mean to enhance user's experience. For example says that how I can detect what language user use on the phone (this appear in start up setting) to auto change my app language. Or perhaps, what is a best way to provide user with multiple language support?

Comment: I don't think bilingual people would like to see their apps changing depending on who they're speaking to. They usually like to set up a language and have it keep that setting.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP was suggesting.  I think he(?)'s asking about making an application conform to the phone's language setting (Settings > region & language > Display language).

Comment: Keith was right, I just wondering if I could detect What is the display language currently used by user. If user change Display language from English to German, my app can detect that change on load and make appropriate change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Resource Files
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx

There is some value in allowing a user to choose the language themselves, in particular if you want to support a language not supported by the phone, ie Chinese on 7.0

Comment: Replaced it with what appears to be the new version of that link.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into settings > keyboard, and then add another language it will give you options when the keyboard comes up so that useless autocorrect is no longer useless when typing in another language.

I had the problem of everything I wrote in spanish being autocorrected.. This is especially annoying when it splits your word into 2 as you are forced to retype it.

When adding a second language, you will have an extra button at the bottom of the keyboard so you can switch between lanugages. This changes the dictionaries also.. I believe you can have as many as you like.