# how can a XAP file contain multiple languages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

As all know, a WP app can contain multiple languages when we submit a .XAP to WP Dev Center.

Now, I found MSDN and other documents but never find the way that a .XAP can contain multiple languages.

I build WP app by VS2012, and selected multiple languages in `Supported Cultures` of `Properties` page, but when I submit it to WP Dev Center found that only English culture was here.

How can I add multiple languages support for my WP app?

Comment: similar question about mulitingual wp7 app is already on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072874/multi-language-feature-support-windows-phone-7

Comment: @ZafarYousafi Tks, It not a same question. I know how to Build a Localized app. My means, when we download a app, it will be show languages which supported. e.g. Skype supported 19 languages display in this page http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/skype/c3f8e570-68b3-4d6a-bdbb-c0a3f4360a51. I just want to add this information into my download page.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try working with the Multilingual App Toolkit?

Have a look over [this](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Adding_multilingual_support_to_your_Windows_Phone_application_using_the_Multilingual_App_Toolkit)!

Hope it helps